# ArangoDB does not match documents with case-insensitivity when using regex operator =~

Tags: arangodb, case-insensitive, aql

I am using enterprise 3.2 and have an issue with regex matching operator **=~**. From the documentation, it appears that I can use string regex and that should be case insensitive. However when tried, it fails to match characters when right hand operand has all lowercase. Attaching screenshot to refer to the issue. This first screenshot shows the document is retured by the query when we use the same case as in the collection.
[image]

Here is the second screenshot that shows that case insensitive regex fails to pull the record.
[image]

Comment: I don't read the docs as to state =~ should be caseinsensitive -- to me it suggests that you have to use `REGEX_TEST(text, regexp, true);` if you want to have a case-insensitive match.

Answer (score 1):

Like Tom already said. You have to use `REGEX_TEST(text, search, caseInsensitive)` for this with `caseInsensitive` set to `true` (see [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Functions/String.html#regextest)).

The operator `=~` is just a short hand for `REGEX_TEST(text, search, false)`.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this thread when I had this problem, but there is also another solution to this. Just want to give it to people who wanted to use =~ operator instead of REGEX_TEST() function.

Example:

```
FOR doc in contacts
FILTER doc.name =~ '(?i)raM'
RETURN doc
```

Another solution could also be (not tested):

```
FOR doc in contacts
FILTER LOWER(doc.name) == LOWER('raM')
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have to use REGEX_TEST. And this is how you do it, with example.

```
FOR doc IN contacts 
    FILTER REGEX_TEST(doc.name, 'anystring_representing_regex', true)
RETURN doc
```